# How to compare two dataframes that have no matching IDs or other attributes using Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have 2 dataframes that are generated differently and there are no IDs in common or other attributes that could be used to create a match between the two. The dataframes don't have the same number of rows, but their schemas are identical. There are all types of datatypes, including timestamps. I tried comparing using different columns but there are no or few matches.
How could I compare the dataframes ?

I was thinking about ordering both dataframes by a timestamp and add an Index (monotonicallyIncreasingId) and then just compare row by row.

Anyway, I feel like this is not the best approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to get the result of each column? or just overall (i.e. Matching rows and Mismatched Rows)

Comment: I want the result of each column and I don't know if my approach is ok or not since I cannot use any keys to compare the rows.

Comment: To compare based on Column Values you'll need some column that can be used as key, do you have any column that can be used to determine the order at least?

Comment: I have a STARTTIME column, timestamp type, that I thought about sorting in ascending order both sides and then compare all columns row by row by adding an Index using monotonicallyIncreasingId

Comment: Even then any anomaly there would impact the whole comparison :/

Comment: That's why I asked for a better solution, because I'm not satisfied with this one.